# Using InStr function to delete only like values from a range

Tags: vba, excel

the following code uses a range to delete rows from a worksheet, my worbook isn't normalised so my question is how can I use the InStr function here to also delete like values, i.e. if "Apple Ltd" is in the range then it would delete rows containing "apple" or vice versa...Is it possible?

Update: Line 28: Requires object @freeman I could not get "Dim Cel as Range" to work, I've inserted as here and at the top of the sheet with the same result. Is the syntax as you've written 'Cel'? Original below

```
 Sub Loop_Example()
    Dim ChkRange As Range
        Dim Firstrow As Long
        Dim Lastrow As Long
        Dim Lrow As Long
        Dim CalcMode As Long
        Dim ViewMode As Long
    Set ChkRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A13")
        With Application
            CalcMode = .Calculation
            .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With
        With Sheet1
            .Select
            ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
            ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
            .DisplayPageBreaks = False
            Firstrow = 2
            Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
                With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
                    If Not IsError(.Value) Then
  If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Value, ChkRange, 0)) Then
    .EntireRow.Delete
  End If
  For Each Cell In ChkRange
        If InStr(1, Cell.Value, .Value) > 0 And Cell.Value <> .Value Then
        'include the 2nd part of the "AND" to ensure you don't delete based
        'on a COMPLETE match, only on a partial match as noted in the comments
        Cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  Next
End If

End With
    Next Lrow
        End With
ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .Calculation = CalcMode
        End With
    End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Loop_Example()
        Dim ChkRange As Range
            Dim Firstrow As Long
            Dim Lastrow As Long
            Dim Lrow As Long
            Dim CalcMode As Long
            Dim ViewMode As Long
        Set ChkRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A13")
            With Application
                CalcMode = .Calculation
                .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                .ScreenUpdating = False
            End With
            With Sheet1
                .Select
                ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
                ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
                .DisplayPageBreaks = False
                Firstrow = 2
                Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
                    With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
                        If Not IsError(.Value) Then
      If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Value, ChkRange, 0)) Then
        .EntireRow.Delete
      End If
      For Each Cell In ChkRange
        Dim Cel As Range
            If InStr(1, Cell.Value, .Value) > 0 And Cell.Value <> .Value Then
            'include the 2nd part of the "AND" to ensure you don't delete based
            'on a COMPLETE match, only on a partial match as noted in the comments
            Cell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
      Next
    End If

    End With
        Next Lrow
            End With
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = True
                .Calculation = CalcMode
            End With
        End Sub
```

Comment: If the entire value exists within another string I wouldn't want the macro to delete it as that would remove lots values

Comment: Yes, but I'd have to delete ones like your example manually

Comment: If the entire string is followed by a space would it not delete those, and any others I could take out manually.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74368/discussion-between-thomas-sharp-and-pnuts).

Answer (score 0):

How can you use `InStr()` to delete an entire row? Modify this part of your code

```
If Not IsError(.Value) Then
  If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Value, ChkRange, 0)) Then
    .EntireRow.Delete
  End If
End If
```

to something like this:

```
Dim cel as range  'put this at the top of your code with your other Dim stmts
If Not IsError(.Value) Then
  If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Value, ChkRange, 0)) Then
    .EntireRow.Delete
  End If
'note this changed row. Note carefully the SPELLING
  for each Cel in ChkRange.Cells
    if Instr(1, Cel.value, .Value) > 0 and ce.lValue <> .Value then
      'include the 2nd part of the "AND" to ensure you don't delete based
       'on a COMPLETE match, only on a partial match as noted in the comments
      cel.EntireRow.Delete
    end if
  next
End If
```

This will likely be quite slow, as you'll have to loop through each cell in `ChkRange` looking to see if `Sheet1.Cells(Lrow,"I").Value` is somewhere in there.

Note: this is off the top of my head and untested, but should work, or at least get you close

Comment: `End If
  For Each Cell In ChkRange
    If InStr(1, Cell.Value, .Value) > 0 And Cell.Value <> .Value Then
      'include the 2nd part of the "AND" to ensure you don't delete based
       'on a COMPLETE match, only on a partial match as noted in the comments
      Cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  Next
End If`  Which object do I need to decalre here?

Comment: @ThomasSharp `Dim Cel as Range` I believe should do the trick. If that's not it, add that to your OP, as it's very difficult to read in comments.

Comment: @ThomasSharp I saw you edited the OP, but I don't see where you put this code in. Maybe paste what you have now, and where you put this as another block of code so we can take another look

Comment: @ThomasSharp, I've put a fix in my sample code above, commenting on the changes. Sorry it wasn't 100% correct the first time, but I did put in a disclaimer... ;)

Comment: thanks but this: `for each Cel in ChkRange.Cells do` is the problem. Yes I put with other Dims initially...

Comment: Gah! Get rid of the `do`. I believe that should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74433/discussion-between-thomas-sharp-and-freeman).